# Children of post-adulterous forbidden union - mamzerim?

Tags: halacha, arayot, mamzer, children

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106005/may-a-man-marry-the-women-with-whom-he-committed-adultery) discusses the marriage of a man with a previously married woman who committed adultery with that man and subsequently divorced. Such a marriage is forbidden.

What would be the status of any kids coming from that post-divorce forbidden union with her paramour?

Would the children she conceived from the adulterer *after* she divorced her first husband be *mamzerim*, since it is forbidden for her to marry the adulterer?

Comment: _Would the children she conceived from the adulterer after she divorced her first husband be mamzerim, since it is forbidden for her to marry the adulterer?_ - No, since it's only a negative "Lav" or a Derabonon.

Answer (score 5):

- If she is still having 
  relations with her husband at the time and is only one off relations G-d forbid with someone else we say in Sotah 27a and Shulchan Aruch even haezer 4,15:

  > אשה מזנה בניה כשרין רוב בעילות אחר הבעל
  >   A woman who is adulterous under her husband, her children are Kosher as most of her relations are with her husband
- If she is extremely promiscuous with other men while with her husband, we are worried her child is a Mamzer unless she says its from her husband ibid:

  > ואם היא פרוצה ביותר, חוששין אף לבנים:
  >   הגה: ומ"מ היא נאמנת לומר על בניה שהם כשרים
- However if she has left her husband without divorcing him, then the child can only be attributed to someone else e.g when her husband goes off to another country and she gets remarried, *then* her child from first and second husband is a Mamzer even after she divorced her first husband. Yevamos 87b [Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 17,56:](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%A0%D7%95)

  > האשה שהלך בעלה למדינה אחרת ובאו ואמרו לה מת בעלך, ונישאת ואחר כך בא בעלה... והוולד מהשני הוא ממזר מהתורה אם הולידה עד שלא גרשה הראשון,אבל אם לא הולידה אלא אחר שמת ראשון או גירשה, אין הוולד משני אלא ממזר דרבנן
  >   Her husband went away and she was told he is dead and she remarried, if her first husband is really alive and comes back her child from her second husband prior to divorce from first husband is a Mamzer *deoraita*.If her first husband divorces her, her child subsequently conceived from her second husband is a Mamzer *derabanan* (since she cannot marry him as a punishment)
- The Ralbach (16th century Rav of Yerushalayim quoted in Beis Shmuel ibid) says that the child is only a Mamzer derabanan after divorcing her first husband in this case where she got married thinking her first husband died as we make a *Knas* (punishment) for not checking properly if her original husband was alive.
  But if she was adulterous on purpose during her first marriage but only  conceived from the adulterer after her first husband divorced her, this child is not a Mamzer at all even though the marriage is forbidden:

  > תשו' רלב"ח אשה שזנתה במזיד הולד שהולידה מבועל אחר גרושי הראשון אף על גב דהיא אסורה לו מ"מ הולד אחר גירושי הראשון אינו ממזר ול"ד לנשאת בטעות דשם משום קנס הוא אבל מזנה ברצון לא שייך קנס

Comment: This answers the question that was in the title but body of the question never asked about in-marriage adultery. The question was always about children conceived post-divorce with the paramour.

Comment: @yishai you havn't read the last 2 paragraphs which say that  if she married thinking her first husband was dead the child from second husband is a Mamzer miderabanan even after the first husband divorces her. but if she is doing adultary then a child concieved from adulterer  after first husband died is not a Mamzer